# SSRS Report Builder Variance %

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder, variance

I am trying to calculate a variance percentage and avoid dividing by 0 errors

This code below works for the overall variance percentage

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!Baseline.Value) = 0, 0, Sum(Fields!test.Value))  / IIf(Sum(Fields!Baseline.Value) = 0, 1, Sum(Fields!Baseline.Value))
```

I am now trying to limit it to a certain category and tried using the below expression

```
    =IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "Resources Capital ",
IIf(Sum(Fields!Baseline.Value) = 0, 0, Sum(Fields!test.Value))
  / IIf(Sum(Fields!Baseline.Value) = 0, 1, Sum(Fields!Baseline.Value)), 0)
```

It does not appear to be looking at the category value as it continues to give me the overall variance. Any help would be appreciated as I am not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving your additional condition to both of the other IIF expressions instead of adding another:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!Baseline.Value) = 0 and Fields!Category.Value = "Resources Capital ", 0, Sum(Fields!test.Value))
  / IIf(Sum(Fields!Baseline.Value) and Fields!Category.Value = "Resources Capital " = 0, 1, Sum(Fields!Baseline.Value)), 0)
```

Comment: I received an error when initially trying it, I changed it to, `=IIf(Sum(Fields!Baseline.Value) = 0 and Fields!Category.Value = "Resources Capital ", 0, Sum(Fields!test.Value))
  / IIf(Sum(Fields!Baseline.Value) = 0 and Fields!Category.Value = "Resources Capital ", 1, Sum(Fields!Baseline.Value))`  It still is not calculating correctly

Comment: My mistake, the sum should be outside the iif statements:

Comment: sum(iif(Fields!Baseline.value = 0 and fields!Category.value = "Resources Capital",0,fields!test.value))/sum(iif(fields!Baseline.value = 0 and fields!Category.value = "Resources Capital", 1,fields!Baseline.value))

Comment: It gave me an #error. This seems like it should be fairly easy but I may have to rethink it.

Comment: I used `=sum(iif(Fields!Baseline.value = CDec(0) and fields!Category.value = "Resources Capital ", CDec(0),
fields!test.value))/sum(iif(fields!Baseline.value = CDec(0) and fields!Category.value = "Resources Capital ", CDec(1),fields!Baseline.value))` I did not receive an error but i should get -188% but instead got 13.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the data?

Comment: Where does the fields!test.value come from? Are you grouping by anything?

Comment: Sorry test was a calculated field I created in Report Builder,  I was having issues  trying to go Baseline-Forecast/Baseline

Comment: So the expression is actually sum(baseline) - sum(forecast)/ sum(baseline)? Grouped by Resource_Type or...?

Comment: Yes but in this case it would be grouped by Category

Comment: Okay, so for all the categories that are not "Resource Capital" you'll get a 0% variance.

    iif(sum(fields!Baseline.value)=cdec(0) and fields!Category.value = "Resource Capital", cdec(0), (sum(fields!Forecast.value) - sum(fields!Baseline.value)))/iif(sum(fields!Baseline.value) = cdec(0) and fields!Category.value = "Resource Capital", cdec(1),sum(fields!Baseline.value))

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Iif inside every SUM of the expression

```
=
IIf(
Sum(IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "Resources Capital",Fields!Baseline.Value,0)) = 0, 
0, 
Sum(IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "Resources Capital",Fields!test.Value,0))
)
/ 
IIf(
Sum(IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "Resources Capital",Fields!Baseline.Value,0)) = 0, 
1, 
Sum( IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "Resources Capital",Fields!Baseline.Value,0))
)
```

An alternative could be using custom code like below

```
Public Function Divider (ByVal Dividend As Double, ByVal Divisor As Double)
If IsNothing(Divisor) Or Divisor = 0
  Return Nothing
Else
  Return Dividend/Divisor
End If
End Function
```

Then you can write your expression like:

```
=Code.Divider(
Sum(IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "Resources Capital",Fields!test.Value,0)),
Sum(IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "Resources Capital",Fields!Baseline.Value,0))
)
```